# How to create AutoBackup SQL database using vb.net?

Tags: database, vb.net, database-backups, auto

I have a vb.net code that s connected to MySQL server and I want to be able to auto backup my database after a particular period of time. I have tried the below code but it is not working.

```
Private Sub ProcessAutoBackup()
    If Me.cboServerName.Text.Trim.Length > 0 Then
        clsSQL.ConnectServer(Me.cboServerName.Text, True)

        For Rec As Integer = 0 To Me.cboDatabaseName.Items.Count - 1
            Select Case Me.cboDatabaseName.Items(Rec).ToString.ToUpper
                Case "MASTER", "TEMPDB", "MODEL", "MSDB", "REPORTSERVER", "REPORTSERVERTEMPDB" 'Dont include System Databases
                Case Else
                    cirProgStatus.Visible = True
                    If Me.chkUseWinRar.Checked = True Then
                        clsSQL.Backup(Me.cboDatabaseName.Items(Rec).ToString, True)
                    Else
                        clsSQL.Backup(Me.cboDatabaseName.Items(Rec).ToString, False)
                    End If

                    Do While clsSQL.theThread.ThreadState = Threading.ThreadState.Running
                        'Wait to finished...
                        cirProgStatus.Value += 1

                        Application.DoEvents()

                        If cirProgStatus.Value = 100 Then
                            cirProgStatus.Value = 0
                        End If

                        Me.cirProgStatus.Enabled = False
                        Me.Refresh()
                        Me.cirProgStatus.Enabled = True
                    Loop
            End Select
        Next
        cirProgStatus.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Firstly, *"it is not working"* is never an adequate description of an issue. You *always* need to explain *exactly* what actually does happen. You need to debug your code and describe its actual behaviour and *exactly* how that differs from your expectation. Apart from that, you have `Backup` and other methods that may be the issue for all we know but we have no knowledge of their implementation. Apart from anything else, that loop is absolutely diabolical. If you ever think you need to call `DoEvents` in a loop, you know you're doing it wrong.

Comment: i go that code online but the code did not backup all the database in the server.... i will happy if i can see new code for Auto Backup database using vb.net, i will be happy